# Conditional Distribution of a Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

For a fixed $t>0$, how to compute the conditional distribution of a Brownian motion at time $t$, $B(t)$, given that $B(2t)=x$?

My reasoning is that this is just equivalent to the distribution of $B(t)$ given $B(0)=x$. So I am guessing that $\mathcal{N}(x,t)$ is the answer, but I am not sure. What looks really odd in my reasoning is the reversed time.

Any thoughts on this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) might help.

Comment: @Batman Is it not assumed that $B(0)=0$ in this problem as well? Or maybe my definition of Brownian motion is wrong...

Comment: @angryavian - Yeah, a brownian motion is pinned to 0 at $t=0, T$. This is slightly different in that $B(2t)$ is not pinned to $0$, but $x$. So, its not the classical brownian bridge, but brownian bridge-like (or depending on who you ask, also a brownian bridge). But, you can do this problem pretty easily without knowing anything about brownian bridges, just the joint distribution of a Brownian Motion.

Comment: @Batman Understood, thanks for the explanation. I was looking at the [last section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge#General_case) of Theoretical Economist's link, which indeed mentions the more general case.

Comment: The original comment  you were replying to was worded badly, so I've replaced it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [joint distribution](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~etheridg/finmath/finan45.pdf) of $\begin{bmatrix} B(s) \\ B(t)\end{bmatrix} $ is a joint Gaussian distribution with mean $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and covariance matrix $\begin{bmatrix} s & s \wedge t \\ t \wedge s & t \end{bmatrix}$.

Note that the conditional distribution is still Gaussian with some well known mean and covariance (which you can calculate via Proposition 3.9 in [these notes](http://hajek.ece.illinois.edu/ECE534Notes.html); Eq. 3.10 has a typo it should read $\hat{E}[X|Y=y] = E[X] + \ldots$)

Comment: Is the cusp symbol the $\min$ function?

Comment: @LTW - yes, it is.